# Change column values using several when conditions

Tags: apache-spark

I want to change values of a column in a dataset according to a mapping list that maps original values of that column to other new values. Each element of the list (colMappingValues) is a string that separates the original values from the new values using a ";".

So for a given column (in the following example colName), I do the following processing to alter the column values as described:

```
for (i=0;i<colMappingValues.size();i++){
   
    //below lists contains all distinct values of a column (colMappingValues[i]) and their target values)
    allValuesChanges = colMappingValues[i].toString().split(";", 2);
                 
     dataset  = dataset.withColumn(colName, when(dataset.col(colName).equalTo(allValuesChanges[0])),allValuesChanges[1]).otherwise(dataset.col(colName));
}
```

which is working but I want it to be efficient to avoid unnecessary iterations. Meaning that I want when the column doesn't contain the value from the list, the call to withColumn() gets ignored.
How to do exactly that in a more efficient way using Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df=df.withColumn("colMappingValuesCsv", functions.lit(colMappingValuesCsv))
            .withColumn("asMap", functions.expr("str_to_map(colMappingValuesCsv,',',';')"))
            .withColumn("ValueColumn", functions.expr("coalesce(asMap[ValueColumn], ValueColumn)"));

df.show(false);
```

Input:

```
+-----------+---+
|ValueColumn|Id |
+-----------+---+
|oldValue1  |1  |
|oldValue2  |2  |
|oldValue1  |3  |
|oldValue2  |4  |
|OtherValue |5  |
+-----------+---+
```

Input Mapping : `oldValue1;newValue1`,`oldValue2;newValue2`

Output (Keeping the intermediate columns for understanding, you can drop them):

```
+-----------+---+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|ValueColumn|Id |colMappingValuesCsv                    |asMap                                           |
+-----------+---+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|newValue1  |1  |oldValue1;newValue1,oldValue2;newValue2|[oldValue1 -> newValue1, oldValue2 -> newValue2]|
|newValue2  |2  |oldValue1;newValue1,oldValue2;newValue2|[oldValue1 -> newValue1, oldValue2 -> newValue2]|
|newValue1  |3  |oldValue1;newValue1,oldValue2;newValue2|[oldValue1 -> newValue1, oldValue2 -> newValue2]|
|newValue2  |4  |oldValue1;newValue1,oldValue2;newValue2|[oldValue1 -> newValue1, oldValue2 -> newValue2]|
|OtherValue |5  |oldValue1;newValue1,oldValue2;newValue2|[oldValue1 -> newValue1, oldValue2 -> newValue2]|
+-----------+---+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: is it necessary to use `str_to_map` or `coalesce` inside a `expr` ?

Comment: str_to_map - yes, as it seems to be not available in functions. I initially wrote coalesce as plain Java only, but to be clean used expr.  Also was not sure how to pass column values to getItem.

Comment: str_to_map is available in functions (as a map function)

Comment: Ok, you can try.. maybe it was not there in the version I used